# Laravel 5.1 code optimisation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way that the below code can be shortened?  It's starting to look a bit messy and I wanted to know if there was a better way.

```
/**
 * Update user.
 *
 * @param $request
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function updateUser($request, $id)
{
    // Get user
    $user = $this->user->find($id);

    // Sync job titles
    if($request->has('job_title'))
    {
        $user->jobTitles()->sync((array)$request->get('job_title'));
    } else {
        $user->jobTitles()->detach();
    }

    // Sync employee types
    if($request->has('employee_type'))
    {
        $user->employeeTypes()->sync((array)$request->get('employee_type'));
    } else {
        $user->employeeTypes()->detach();
    }

    if($request->has('status')) {
        $data = $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'status');
    } else {
        $data = $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
    }

    // Save user changes
    return $this->user->whereId($id)->update($data);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would have done:

- Extracted the ManyToMany relationships to their own methods.
- Initialized the `$data` variable and overridden it if necessary.
- Removed the comments. The code is readable enough, no need for them

Code:

```
public function updateUser($request, $id)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($id);
    $data = $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

    $this->syncJobTitles($user);
    $this->syncEmployeeTypes($user);

    if($request->has('status')) {
        $data['status'] = $request->status;
    }

    return $user->update($data);
}

private function syncJobTitles($user)
{
    if(request()->has('job_title'))
    {
        $user->jobTitles()->sync((array) request()->get('job_title'));
    } else {
        $user->jobTitles()->detach();
    }
}

private function syncEmployeeTypes($user)
{
    if(request()->has('employee_type'))
    {
        $user->employeeTypes()->sync((array) request()->get('employee_type'));
    } else {
        $user->employeeTypes()->detach();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to refactor that code:

If that code is only used on that part of your code you could leave it there or

**Option 1**
Move that business logic to the user model

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
  ...
  public function applySomeRule($request) 
  {
    if($request->has('job_title')) {
      $this->jobTitles()->sync((array)$request->get('job_title'));
    } else {
      $this->jobTitles()->detach();
    }

    // Sync employee types
    if($request->has('employee_type')) {
      $this->employeeTypes()->sync((array)$request->get('employee_type'));
    } else {
      $this->employeeTypes()->detach();
    }
  }
}
```

And your controller could finish like

```
public function updateUser($request, $id)
{
    // Get user
    $user = $this->user->find($id);
    $user->applySomeRule($request);

    if($request->has('status')) {
        $data = $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'status');
    } else {
        $data = $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
    }

    // Save user changes
    return $this->user->whereId($id)->update($data);
}
```

**Option 2** If that business logic is used on different controller methods you can use [Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware), so that you move that logic to middleware and in your route definition you use the middleware you created, let's say SomeRuleMiddleware.

Your routes would look like:

```
Route::put('user/{id}', [
     'middleware' => 'SomeRuleMiddleware', 
     'uses' => 'YourController@updateUser'
]);
```

**Option 3** You could move all your business logic to Repositories (read about [Repository Pattern](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/)) and [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles, that way your logic and rules will keep on Repositories and your controllers would keep clean, something like this:

```
class YourController extends Controller 
{
  protected $userRepo;

  public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepo)
  {
    $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
  }

  public function updateUser($request, $id)
  {
    $data = $request->all();
    $result = $this->userRepo->updateUser($id, $data);

    return $result;
  }
}
```